# Unable to install npm on ubuntu 14.04 due to broken packages error

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

Tried installing npm on ubuntu 14.04 however the following error has occurred

```
gwt@gwt-Aspire-E1-571:~$ sudo apt-get install npm

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree 

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed

       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
gwt@gwt-Aspire-E1-571:~$
```

Kindly advice a solution to this problem as unable to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Hope this works out!

Comment: i have tried but their is no positive response. i have install npm from synaptic manager but  in command line throws msg The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install npm
Tried code : npm -v